# SSRS 2005 - http://<servername>/reports error

Tags: reportingservices-2005

We have recently configured SQL SERVER 2005 reporting server and it works when I go to `http://<servername>/reportserver`. But when I want to access `http://<servername>/reports`, I am getting the error.

"The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request"

After going through few articles online about how to fix it...
I have tried changing some code in the RSWebApplication.config  file.

```
<UI>
<ReportServerUrl>http://<servername>/reportserver</ReportServerUrl>
<ReportServerVirtualDirectory></ReportServerVirtualDirectory>
<ReportBuilderTrustLevel>FullTrust</ReportBuilderTrustLevel>
</UI>
```

But it did not work. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

here is the log...

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.GetSecureMethods()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.RSWebServiceWrapper.GetSecureMethods()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.ValidateConnection()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel(HttpsLevel level)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
w3wp!ui!7!9/8/2011-13:58:39:: e ERROR: Exception in ShowErrorPage: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg) at    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
```

Comment: @PreetSangha -- I added event log in the main post. Please review it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look like a security issue. Might want to examine this [MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ec5fdd41-97f5-4da6-9e75-5f08e305bd52/) there seems to be number of possibilities. Let us know if any of them work.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a security issue, which we are still trying to figure out. Thanks for your help on this.